# undefined function dcount in expression

Tags: undefined-function, dcount

I am using Access 2016. I am using dcount in my query however I am getting this error "undefined function dcount in expression". Any idea how can I fix this issue?
here is my syntax
SELECT Table1.Supplier, Table1.Spec, DCount("[Supplier]","[Table1]","[Supplier]='" & Table1.Supplier & "'") AS SupplierDuplicate FROM Table1;

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are missing references in your project.
Press ALT+F11 to open the Microsoft Basic for Applications IDE, then go to Tools menu, References and make sure there are no required libraries missing.

[image]